# Lex chatbot and wso2 authentication

Tags: wso2, amazon-lex

We have a mobile application in which we want to integrate aws lex chatbot.We are using wso2 authentication for mobile app to authenticate user. Can we propogate this wso2 access token to authenticate user in lex chatbot as well?